# React virtualized list keep scroll position on window resize

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have a list of contacts.
If the user scrolled down to "Simon" and then resized the window, the scroll position jumps to the top (equal to 0) and i want it to stay at the same position.
I tryied saving the scroll position to the state using **onScroll** like this:

```
    this.savePosition(params.scrollTop);
```

and then on window **resize** event to read the position from the state and scroll to there like this:

```
    this.ref.current.scrollToPosition(this.state.scrollPosition);
```

but the problem is, the resize event causes onScroll to happen and **onResize** the state is always getting updated to 0 so my state is worth nothing.
How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Instead of scrolling to position via resize event, i do it via scrollTop like this: `scrollTop={this.state.scrollPosition}`